# How to get known Windows folder path with Node

Tags: node.js, windows, winapi

I need to access per-machine configuration data in my Node application running on Windows. I've found this documentation for how to find the location:

[Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files if I Target Multiple OS Versions?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/)

So, in my case, I would like to get the path for `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` (or `FOLDERID_ProgramData`). However, the examples are all in C, and I would prefer to not have to write a C extension for this.

Is there any other way to access these paths from Node, or should I just hardcode them?

Comment: Definitely DO NOT hard-code them. APIs to get the paths exist for a reason - users can change them. So you have to use what is actually configured.

Comment: agreed, but when the operating systems make it this hard to access such basic things, sometimes it's just not worth it...

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research, I've found that it's possible to call the relevant Windows API proc. (SHGetKnownFolderPath) to get these folder locations, see docs at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx.

We call the APi using the FFI npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi.

It is possible to find the GUIDs for any known folder here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is a script that finds the location of several common folders,
some of the code is a little hacky, but is easily cleaned up.

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
const ref = require('ref');

const shell32 = new ffi.Library('Shell32', {
    SHGetKnownFolderPath: ['int', [ ref.refType('void'), 'int', ref.refType('void'), ref.refType(ref.refType("char"))]]
});

function parseGUID(guidStr) {
    var fields = guidStr.split('-');
    var a1 = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length;  i++) {
        var a2 = [...Buffer.from(fields[i], 'hex')];
        if (i < 3) a2 = a2.reverse();
        a1 = a1.concat(a2);
    }
    return new Buffer(a1);
}

function getWindowsKnownFolderPath(pathGUID) {
    let guidPtr = parseGUID(pathGUID);
    guidPtr.type = ref.types.void;

    let pathPtr = ref.alloc(ref.refType(ref.refType("void")));

    let status = shell32.SHGetKnownFolderPath(guidPtr, 0, ref.NULL, pathPtr);
    if (status !== 0) {
        return "Error occurred getting path: " + status;
    }

    let pathStr = ref.readPointer(pathPtr, 0, 200);
    return pathStr.toString('ucs2').substring(0, (pathStr.indexOf('\0\0') + 1)/2);
}

// See this link for a complete list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx 
const WindowsKnownFolders = {
   ProgramData: "62AB5D82-FDC1-4DC3-A9DD-070D1D495D97",
   Windows: "F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23",
   ProgramFiles: "905E63B6-C1BF-494E-B29C-65B732D3D21A",
   Documents: "FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7"
}

// Enumerate common folders.
for(let [k,v] of Object.entries(WindowsKnownFolders)) {
   console.log(`${k}: `, getWindowsKnownFolderPath(v));   
}
```

Comment: I've noted that as well, but I've not found any documentation that guarantees that these variables are always present. Currently I'm using this solution.

Comment: Yeah, they are usually good, but like you say not guaranteed.

Comment: Hey @Jonatan, I've updated my answer with a method of pulling known folder paths from the relevant windows API (SHGetKnownFolderPath), this should do what you want.